# Keeping a singular reference to a commit across branches

Tags: git

I need to separate out several commits that exist in a project branch into an intermediary branch (`my/fix-branch`), which will eventually go into master, then merged back into the project branch when released.

My issue is when it comes time to do that merge from master to `project/branch`, the merge commits of the feature branches into the intermediary branch are duplicates.

How can I keep the proper references so that the project history remains clean? There should only be one record/hash of a commit across the entire repo, no matter how many branches they're moved to and from.

[image: Repo layout]

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate commits are common when cherry-picking.

But in your case, ideally (if you are alone on this repository), when released, you would rebase `project/branch` on top of the latest release `master`: any duplicate commit would not be duplicated during that rebase.